# Confetti effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

I am working to replicate the below screen shot. For that i am working on the following code. Currently, i am stuck to figure out a way to achieve the desired result of mixed flake shapes with the desired sizes. Can anyone please share their experience to solve this problem. Any recommendations like using SVG etc would also be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
(function () {
    // globals
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var W;
    var H;
    var mp = 150; //max particles
    var particles = [];
    var angle = 0;
    var tiltAngle = 0;
    var confettiActive = true;
    var animationComplete = true;
    var deactivationTimerHandler;
    var reactivationTimerHandler;
    var animationHandler;

    // objects

    var particleColors = {
        colorOptions: ["DodgerBlue", "OliveDrab", "Gold", "pink", "SlateBlue", "lightblue", "Violet", "PaleGreen", "SteelBlue", "SandyBrown", "Chocolate", "Crimson"],
        colorIndex: 0,
        colorIncrementer: 0,
        colorThreshold: 10,
        getColor: function () {
            if (this.colorIncrementer >= 10) {
                this.colorIncrementer = 0;
                this.colorIndex++;
                if (this.colorIndex >= this.colorOptions.length) {
                    this.colorIndex = 0;
                }
            }
            this.colorIncrementer++;
            return this.colorOptions[this.colorIndex];
        }
    }

    function confettiParticle(color) {
        this.x = Math.random() * W; // x-coordinate
        this.y = (Math.random() * H) - H; //y-coordinate
        this.r = RandomFromTo(10, 30); //radius;
        this.d = (Math.random() * mp) + 10; //density;
        this.color = color;
        this.tilt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10;
        this.tiltAngleIncremental = (Math.random() * 0.07) + .05;
        this.tiltAngle = 0;

        this.draw = function () {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = this.r / 2;
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
            ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.tilt + (this.r / 4), this.y);
            ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.tilt, this.y + this.tilt + (this.r / 4));
            return ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SetGlobals();
        InitializeButton();
        InitializeConfetti();

        $(window).resize(function () {
            W = window.innerWidth;
            H = window.innerHeight;
            canvas.width = W;
            canvas.height = H;
        });

    });

    function InitializeButton() {
        $('#stopButton').click(DeactivateConfetti);
        $('#startButton').click(RestartConfetti);
    }

    function SetGlobals() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        W = window.innerWidth;
        H = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = W;
        canvas.height = H;
    }

    function InitializeConfetti() {
        particles = [];
        animationComplete = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
            var particleColor = particleColors.getColor();
            particles.push(new confettiParticle(particleColor));
        }
        StartConfetti();
    }

    function Draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
        var results = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
            (function (j) {
                results.push(particles[j].draw());
            })(i);
        }
        Update();

        return results;
    }

    function RandomFromTo(from, to) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
    }


    function Update() {
        var remainingFlakes = 0;
        var particle;
        angle += 0.01;
        tiltAngle += 0.1;

        for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
            particle = particles[i];
            if (animationComplete) return;

            if (!confettiActive && particle.y < -15) {
                particle.y = H + 100;
                continue;
            }

            stepParticle(particle, i);

            if (particle.y <= H) {
                remainingFlakes++;
            }
            CheckForReposition(particle, i);
        }

        if (remainingFlakes === 0) {
            StopConfetti();
        }
    }

    function CheckForReposition(particle, index) {
        if ((particle.x > W + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > H) && confettiActive) {
            if (index % 5 > 0 || index % 2 == 0) //66.67% of the flakes
            {
                repositionParticle(particle, Math.random() * W, -10, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10);
            } else {
                if (Math.sin(angle) > 0) {
                    //Enter from the left
                    repositionParticle(particle, -5, Math.random() * H, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10);
                } else {
                    //Enter from the right
                    repositionParticle(particle, W + 5, Math.random() * H, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function stepParticle(particle, particleIndex) {
        particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncremental;
        particle.y += (Math.cos(angle + particle.d) + 3 + particle.r / 2) / 2;
        particle.x += Math.sin(angle);
        particle.tilt = (Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle - (particleIndex / 3))) * 15;
    }

    function repositionParticle(particle, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, tilt) {
        particle.x = xCoordinate;
        particle.y = yCoordinate;
        particle.tilt = tilt;
    }

    function StartConfetti() {
        W = window.innerWidth;
        H = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = W;
        canvas.height = H;
        (function animloop() {
            if (animationComplete) return null;
            animationHandler = requestAnimFrame(animloop);
            return Draw();
        })();
    }

    function ClearTimers() {
        clearTimeout(reactivationTimerHandler);
        clearTimeout(animationHandler);
    }

    function DeactivateConfetti() {
        confettiActive = false;
        ClearTimers();
    }

    function StopConfetti() {
        animationComplete = true;
        if (ctx == undefined) return;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    }

    function RestartConfetti() {
        ClearTimers();
        StopConfetti();
        reactivationTimerHandler = setTimeout(function () {
            confettiActive = true;
            animationComplete = false;
            InitializeConfetti();
        }, 100);

    }

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
            return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
    })();
})();
```

JS Fiddle link: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Javalsu/vxP5q/743/embedded/result/)

[image]

Comment: So what the question is is how can I change the shape of the script I found from rectangles to triangles?

Comment: @epascarello I am looking for mixer of the shapes which includes triangles(not equilateral triangles), squares and rectangles and those all needs to be randomly generated.

Comment: Start by adding a `shape` parameter to the `confettiParticle`. The particle draw function needs to check what shape it's drawing or be a separate function for different shapes. Get back to us if you have problems writing the code.

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46906672/3877726 confetti with turbulence and a little parallax. Can render and shape you want.